# Can't finish Google sheets API authorization using ezsheets

Tags: python, google-api, google-sheets-api

I am trying to do the initial steps of creating a Python script using ezsheets. In their manual, they suggest that you run the script with just  `import ezsheets` and nothing else so that you can do the API authorization before you move forward.

I am stuck there. Does anyone know why I can't finish the authorization?

Here is literally all of my configuration.

```
import ezsheets
import os
```

Here is what happens when I run the Python script.

1. A tab is opened and I choose a google account.
2. I allow the script to "See, edit, create, and delete your spreadsheets in Google Drive"
3. I get a message saying I can't connect to localhost:8080

I looked around here and found someone who suggested running `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080 --bind 127.0.0.1` but that hasn't helped. When I do that I get the following messages in the terminal.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Oct/2020 15:53:58] "GET /?state=O1Db0mYPwVjU7veAmqiP8JBhTontLw&code=4/5gEFgsaDX0-7nGYfGmLEzuJxympuGyvlq0cJF5A7i4b4E-1fO1qvmFyK2_2BkI9bZU0czi4W5k980r_mIdbulWo&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Oct/2020 15:53:58] code 404, message File not found
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Oct/2020 15:53:58] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Some notes:
I have created an OAuth 2.0 Client ID.
The user type is internal.
I am part of a G Suite. I have added the ID to G Suite and allowed all of the expected API calls.

The installed library versions are

```
EZSheets                 2020.10.10
google-api-core          1.23.0
google-api-python-client 1.12.4
google-auth              1.22.1
google-auth-httplib2     0.0.4
google-auth-oauthlib     0.4.1
googleapis-common-protos 1.52.0
```

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: please edit your question and include your code.

Comment: I did. It's the two includes. That is literally everything. As described in the manual for ezsheets, you're supposed to run the code with just the include and go through authorization. I can't get past that step. Because of that I have no code yet besides the two includes.

Comment: have a look at the configuration of Google API: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python
after following the steps described there, I was able to successfully authorize the credentials, creating the necessary tokens and afterwards I am able to authorise and use both: ezsheets as well es the official google sheets api